# Plugin using tag pairs as "parameters". Possible?

Tags: plugin

Is it possible to use tag pairs as parameters?

Take the code below

```
{exp:utilities:foo}
    {qux}abcdef{/qux}
    {lux}12345789{/lux}
{/exp:utilities:foo}
```

Normally, using `parameters`, you are going to do this

```
$qux    = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('qux');
```

Inside the plugin, is there something I can call to get the values between the tag pairs just like the code above?

My motivation for doing this is because using "parameters" for plugins usually result in a parse order issue for me.Some people seem to have the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423727/changing-an-expressionengine-plugins-parse-order) too.

**NOTE:**

I aiming to use the parameters to do some processing and return a single string for the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll have to fetch / process them from tagdata yourself.
$this->EE->TMPL->var_pair will have an array of var-pairs you can walk.
Then compare / preg_match() them on the keys/tags you're looking for.

You can see by looking at an example in a small calendar class i made:
[Calender_entries (github, highlighted)](https://github.com/GDmac/calendar_entries/blob/master/system/expressionengine/third_party/calendar_entries/pi.calendar_entries.php#L52-L68)

Comment: Nice! I could peruse the regular expression to parse what is inside the tags.